# How to properly include dependencies in R-package?

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I was trying now for several hours to build a package in R and getting a bit desperate about how slowly I progress. I managed quite fast to build a package with no dependencies, everything works fine. Due to recommendations in several posts, I'm using R Studio, devtools and Roxygen2 (being on Windows). With dependencies, I get problems when I CHECK (e.g. with devtools::check() ):

> checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE Namespace in Imports field
>   not imported from: 'ggplot2'   All declared Imports should be used.
>   See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter 'Creating R
>   packages' of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

Furthermore, check() deletes the `import(ggplot2)` line in the NAMESPACE. If I do check(document=F), it gives an cryptic error about a `digest` package which is not loaded. I read 'Writing R Extensions' - 1.1.3 Package Dependencies and Hadley's Wiki concerning how to write packages, but couldn't solve my problem. DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files of other R packages from CRAN don't look different to mine (for my eyes)?

**Question:** What am I doing wrong? Sorry for such a basic question, but I am at a loss and most step-by-step tutorials I've seen so far stop before explaining dependencies.

So far, I have 3 files: 
A DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: test
Type: Package
Title: Foo
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-03-21
Author: Bar
Maintainer: Foo <bar@mail.com>
Description: Blubb
Imports:
    ggplot2
License: GPL-3
```

A NAMESPACE:

```
export(is.equal.null)
import(ggplot2)
```

A R-File:

```
#' Extension of compare to include NULLs
#'
#' Works as an extension to usual compare
#' Compares two basic objects which in addition to usual compare can be NULL
#' Intuitive output: TRUE if both are equal or NULL resp., FALSE if both are unequal or only one is NULL
#'
#' @param obj1 Basic object like \code{numeric, char, boolean, NULL}
#' @param obj2 Basic object like \code{numeric, char, boolean, NULL}
#' @keywords compare
#' @export
#' @examples
#' is.equal.null(5,5)  # TRUE
#' is.equal.null(5,NULL)  # FALSE
#' is.equal.null(NULL,NULL)  # TRUE
is.equal.null <- function(obj1, obj2) {
  # Small helper function to generalize comparison to comparison of NULL
  # returns TRUE if both are NULL, and FALSE if only one of the objects is NULL
  bool <- obj1==obj2 
  #qplot(obj1)
  if (length(bool)) return(bool)
  if (is.null(obj1) & is.null(obj2)) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to declare imports in **two** places:

1. The DESCRIPTION file. You should have a line similar to:

   ```
   Imports: ggplot2, pkg1, pkg2
   ```
2. The NAMESPACE file. Here you declare the packages you need

   ```
   import(ggplot2)
   ```

   or to avoid namespace clashes

   ```
   importFrom(ggplot2, geom_point)
   ```

   You can get roxygen2 to maintain the NAMESPACE file using the `@import` and `@importFrom` tags.

In your example your DESCRIPTION file looks OK, but you haven't added the necessary functions to the NAMESPACE.

Comment: At the top of my NAMESPACE file I import several packages, and I have them all listed under Imports in my DESCRIPTION file, but they are still not being installed when I install my package. Am I missing something? Also, @csgillespie, what do you mean when you say you can get roxygen2 to maintain the NAMESPACE file. I have been re-adding these imports after I `roxygenise` instead

Comment: roxygen2 can generate the namespace file.

Comment: Yes, but when I use roxygen2 to generate the namespace file it does not include the imports, it only includes the exports, so I have to add them manually

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135971/namespace-not-generated-by-roxygen2-skipped-confusion-with-hadley-book

Comment: Thank you @csgillespie ! Now the NAMESPACE file is properly created, but the dependencies still don't install when I install the package from source. But this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 4):

A standard workflow, as described by Hadley, is:

```
library(devtools)

# Add a dependency
use_package('tibble')

# (Re-)build NAMESPACE
document()

# Reload the package: CTRL-L or
load_all()
```