# RStudio: Building package with roxygen2. Not producing NAMESPACE file

Tags: r, rstudio, roxygen2

This is my first time building an R package, and doing it with the help of devtools and roxygen2. After writing a simple func in the R directory and making a DESCRIPTION file with devtools, I try to build and reload for the first time but I get an error -

> ==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
>
> First time using roxygen2 4.0. Upgrading automatically...
>
> Documentation completed
>
> ==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source TestPack
>
> ...
>
> ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required

Which is odd because I have selected in my build configurations that roxygen2 should be making this for me. A man directory is made when building and reloading but nothing else.

Comment: just create a blank NAMESPACE file. on the command line e.g., `touch NAMESPACE`  then rerun `document()`

Comment: If your simple function does not require any imports and is not exported it may be that the file is not created.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain I can make a blank NAMESPACE and then it works fine. I was thinking I didn't have to do that.

Comment: yeah, i don't understand why that happens, i guess its conservative about making changes to your files, though i'd think if a namespace file didn't exist, it is a safe thing to create one

Comment: Somehow, i had the same problem and I figured out that after a crash of my Rstudio, it had automatically unselected all the build options for roxygen2, that was the reason of the error.