# using org.Hs.eg.db in R package

Tags: r

I have a R package that I created and I use this line in some function:

`de.genes= AnnotationDbi::select(org.Hs.eg.db, columns = c("SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"), keys = de.genes, keytype="SYMBOL")`

when I call this function after installing the package I get an error :
`Error in AnnotationDbi::select(org.Hs.eg.db, columns = c("SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"),  : object 'org.Hs.eg.db' not found`

it works only if I runs `library(org.Hs.eg.db)` before I call the function or inside it.

thanks for help.

Comment: Did you list org.Hs.eg.db as a dependency in your package DESCRIPTION file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565024/how-to-properly-include-dependencies-in-r-package for more info

Comment: Yes that was the problem.
Thanks very much!!